# What medal did the referee in the FIFA world cup get?

Tags: football, officiating, world-cup, fifa, awards

The referee, Nicola Rizzoli, seemed to have received a medal in yesterday's finale. What kind of medal is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would a momento or souvenir, rather than a medal. This is common in all sports, to give the officials souvenirs of a significant moment in their officiating careers.